# How to count word from a column when consecutive cells are equal in a different column using shell script!

Tags: bash, shell-script, bioinformatics

I'm trying to count the number of `C_R` and `S_R` in column 9 when consecutive cells in column 2, column 3, and column 1 are the same. The file is in bed format (tab-separated format). The original file is huge and column 1 defines chromosome number. The first few lines of the file look like this,

```
chr1    10200   10300   8   10000   10214   100 214 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10009   10233   100 224 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10014   10220   100 206 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10045   10215   100 170 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10068   10209   100 141 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10074   10300   100 226 C_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10182   10283   100 101 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10182   10387   100 205 C_R
chr1    10300   10400   4   10182   10387   100 205 S_R
chr1    10300   10400   4   10331   10467   100 136 S_R
chr1    10300   10400   4   10346   10461   100 115 S_R
chr1    10300   10400   4   10352   10468   100 116 S_R
chr1    10400   10500   3   10331   10467   100 136 S_R
chr1    10400   10500   3   10346   10461   100 115 S_R
chr1    10400   10500   3   10352   10468   100 116 S_R
chr1    11000   11100   2   11024   11163   100 139 S_R
chr1    11000   11100   2   11024   11188   100 164 S_R
chr1    11100   11200   3   11024   11163   100 139 S_R
chr1    11100   11200   3   11024   11188   100 164 S_R
chr1    11100   11200   3   11127   11296   100 169 S_R
chr1    11200   11300   1   11127   11296   100 169 S_R
chr1    11400   11500   2   11412   11561   100 149 S_R
chr1    11400   11500   2   11457   11608   100 151 S_R
chr1    11500   11600   3   11412   11561   100 149 S_R
chr1    11500   11600   3   11457   11608   100 151 C_R
chr1    11500   11600   3   11574   11744   100 170 S_R
chr1    11600   11700   3   11457   11608   100 151 S_R
chr1    11600   11700   3   11574   11744   100 170 C_R
chr1    11600   11700   3   11640   11815   100 175 S_R
chr1    11700   11800   4   11574   11744   100 170 S_R
chr1    11700   11800   4   11640   11815   100 175 C_R
chr1    11700   11800   4   11784   11963   100 179 S_R
chr1    11700   11800   4   11791   11936   100 145 S_R
```

In this above table first 8 rows the col 1, 2, 3 are same
so, the tentative output file would look like

```
chr1    10200   10300   2   6
chr1    10300   10400   0   4
chr1    10400   10500   0   3
chr1    11000   11100   0   2
chr1    11100   11200   0   3
chr1    11200   11300   0   1
chr1    11400   11500   0   2
chr1    11500   11600   1   2
chr1    11600   11700   1   2
chr1    11700   11800   1   3
```

Where in ouput file, col 4 is `C_R` and col 5 is `S_R`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That could be done with `awk` with something like:

```
awk 'function report() {
       if (n) print last_key, 0+count["C_R"], 0+count["S_R"]
     }
     {key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3}
     key != last_key {report(); n = 0; split("", count); last_key = key}
     {count[$9]++; n++}
     END {report()}' <your-file
```

If the input fields are meant to be TAB-delimited, you may want to add `-F '\t' -v OFS='\t'` to specify the input and  output file separators. By default `FS` (the input field separator as set by `-F`) is a space character which has a special meaning: any sequence of blanks delimit fields and leading and trailing blanks are discarded or IOW fields are sequences of non-blank characters so there can't be any empty field; and `OFS` is a space as well, simply meaning fields on output are separated with a single space.

Comment: Beauty. Is there a particular reason for using OFS rather FS when populating key?

Comment: @tink, the  key ends up being printed, `print key, x, y` is the same as `print key OFS x OFS y` so we  want to make sure the same delimiter is used to separate all the fields.

Comment: OK, but if none is set explicitly FS == OFS == "any amount of whitespace". So OFS is just for documentation/clarity purposes?

Comment: @tink, or for the case where on would want to set different FS or OFS. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a GNU `awk` (`gawk`, the default `awk` on most Linux systems) approach. Note that I am assuming the columns are tab-separated here, but since that looks like a bed file or a bedpe file, both of which require tabs, I am reasonably sure that is correct.

```
$ gawk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' -v type1="C_R" -v type2="S_R" '
  { 
    a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3][$NF]++; 
  } 
  END{ 
    for (i in a){  
      print i,0+a[i][type1],0+a[i][type2]
    }
}' file.bed 
chr1    11200   11300   0   1
chr1    11700   11800   1   3
chr1    10300   10400   0   4
chr1    11000   11100   0   2
chr1    10400   10500   0   3
chr1    11500   11600   1   2
chr1    11400   11500   0   2
chr1    11100   11200   0   3
chr1    11600   11700   1   2
chr1    10200   10300   2   6
```

#### Explanation

`-F'\t'` sets the input field separator to tab, and `-v OFS='\t'` sets the output field separator to tab. Next, we set two more variables, `type1` ad `type2` to use in the script.

The main body of the script is just `a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3][$NF]++;`. This uses the three first fields, separated by the output field separator (`OFS` which is a tab, in our case) as the first keys to the two dimensional array `a`. The second key is the last field (`$NF`) and we just increment the value by one. As a result, the `a` array counts the number of times each chr, start and end position were found with each of the possible last fields.

Once this has finished, in the `END{ }` block, we iterate over all keys of the array `a` (the chr, start and end positions), and then print out, for each of the two possible last fields, `type1` and `type2`, the chr, start and end positions (the value of `i`) and then the number of times each possible last field was seen with those three first fields (`0+a[i][type1],0+a[i][type2]`). We need the `0+` there so that if the specific last field hasn't been seen with these chr, start and end positions, we will get a `0` instead of an empty field or an error.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.split(/\s+/);  \
            my %hash.push:  [Z=>] @a.map(*.[0..2]), @a.map(*.[*-1]);  \
            put join "\t", .key, (.value.map: * eq "C_R")>>.Int.sum,  \
                (.value.map: * eq "S_R")>>.Int.sum  for %hash.sort;'  file
```

Here's an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Above `lines` are `map`ped into and `split` on whitespace. The result is saved into `@a` array. A `%hash` is declared and Raku's `[Z=>]`  reduction meta-operator is used to `push` key/value pairs onto it, with `.[0..2]` the first three columns as **key** and the `.[*-1]` last column as **value**.  In the last statement the `value`s are checked for string `eq`uivalence to both `C_R` and `S_R`; each Boolean result is converted to an `Int`, `sum`med, and out`put` as columns.

Sample Input:

```
chr1    10200   10300   8   10000   10214   100 214 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10009   10233   100 224 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10014   10220   100 206 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10045   10215   100 170 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10068   10209   100 141 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10074   10300   100 226 C_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10182   10283   100 101 S_R
chr1    10200   10300   8   10182   10387   100 205 C_R
chr1    10300   10400   4   10182   10387   100 205 S_R
chr1    10300   10400   4   10331   10467   100 136 S_R
chr1    10300   10400   4   10346   10461   100 115 S_R
chr1    10300   10400   4   10352   10468   100 116 S_R
chr1    10400   10500   3   10331   10467   100 136 S_R
chr1    10400   10500   3   10346   10461   100 115 S_R
chr1    10400   10500   3   10352   10468   100 116 S_R
chr1    11000   11100   2   11024   11163   100 139 S_R
chr1    11000   11100   2   11024   11188   100 164 S_R
chr1    11100   11200   3   11024   11163   100 139 S_R
chr1    11100   11200   3   11024   11188   100 164 S_R
chr1    11100   11200   3   11127   11296   100 169 S_R
chr1    11200   11300   1   11127   11296   100 169 S_R
chr1    11400   11500   2   11412   11561   100 149 S_R
chr1    11400   11500   2   11457   11608   100 151 S_R
chr1    11500   11600   3   11412   11561   100 149 S_R
chr1    11500   11600   3   11457   11608   100 151 C_R
chr1    11500   11600   3   11574   11744   100 170 S_R
chr1    11600   11700   3   11457   11608   100 151 S_R
chr1    11600   11700   3   11574   11744   100 170 C_R
chr1    11600   11700   3   11640   11815   100 175 S_R
chr1    11700   11800   4   11574   11744   100 170 S_R
chr1    11700   11800   4   11640   11815   100 175 C_R
chr1    11700   11800   4   11784   11963   100 179 S_R
chr1    11700   11800   4   11791   11936   100 145 S_R
```

Sample Output:

```
chr1 10200 10300    2   6
chr1 10300 10400    0   4
chr1 10400 10500    0   3
chr1 11000 11100    0   2
chr1 11100 11200    0   3
chr1 11200 11300    0   1
chr1 11400 11500    0   2
chr1 11500 11600    1   2
chr1 11600 11700    1   2
chr1 11700 11800    1   3
```

*[ In the last `put` statement, replace `.key` with `.key.split(" ").join("\t")` if you want all columns tab-separated ].*

---

Note, it can often be quite instructive to look at intermediate steps, so here's Raku's internal representation of the data (`.raku`) just before the final 2-column `sum`ming:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.split(/\s+/); my %hash.push:  [Z=>] @a.map(*.[0..2]), @a.map(*.[*-1]); .raku.say for %hash.sort;'  file
"chr1 10200 10300" => $["S_R", "S_R", "S_R", "S_R", "S_R", "C_R", "S_R", "C_R"]
"chr1 10300 10400" => $["S_R", "S_R", "S_R", "S_R"]
"chr1 10400 10500" => $["S_R", "S_R", "S_R"]
"chr1 11000 11100" => $["S_R", "S_R"]
"chr1 11100 11200" => $["S_R", "S_R", "S_R"]
"chr1 11200 11300" => "S_R"
"chr1 11400 11500" => $["S_R", "S_R"]
"chr1 11500 11600" => $["S_R", "C_R", "S_R"]
"chr1 11600 11700" => $["S_R", "C_R", "S_R"]
"chr1 11700 11800" => $["S_R", "C_R", "S_R", "S_R"]
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Using the TSV-aware utility Miller (`mlr`) to read the input as a header-less TSV file, picking out only the neccecary columns (using `cut`), collecting/collapsing the values of the 9th column into a `;`-delimited list for each combination of column 1, 2, and 3 (using `nest`), and then counting the number of `C_R` and `S_R` strings that were collected for each remaining record (with a `put` expression).  The collapsed values in column 9 are finally dropped (with `cut -x`).

```bash
mlr --from=file --tsv -N \
    cut -f 1,2,3,9 then \
    nest --ivar ';' -f 9 then \
    put '
        a = splita($9,";");
        for (k in ["C_R","S_R"]) {
            $[k] = count(select(a, func(e) { return e == k }))
        }' then \
    cut -x -f 9
```

Given the data in the question, this would generate the following tab-delimited output:

```
chr1    10200   10300   2       6
chr1    10300   10400   0       4
chr1    10400   10500   0       3
chr1    11000   11100   0       2
chr1    11100   11200   0       3
chr1    11200   11300   0       1
chr1    11400   11500   0       2
chr1    11500   11600   1       2
chr1    11600   11700   1       2
chr1    11700   11800   1       3
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution produces a slightly different output format:

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $9}' input |
    sort |
    uniq -c
   2 chr1 10200 10300 C_R
   6 chr1 10200 10300 S_R
   4 chr1 10300 10400 S_R
   3 chr1 10400 10500 S_R
   2 chr1 11000 11100 S_R
   3 chr1 11100 11200 S_R
   1 chr1 11200 11300 S_R
   2 chr1 11400 11500 S_R
   1 chr1 11500 11600 C_R
   2 chr1 11500 11600 S_R
   1 chr1 11600 11700 C_R
   2 chr1 11600 11700 S_R
   1 chr1 11700 11800 C_R
   3 chr1 11700 11800 S_R
```

The `awk` invocation simply removes the fields that are extraneous to the sorting sequence, then the output from `sort` is passed to `uniq`, which counts the number of times each unique tuple occurs.